# css fixed positioned div disapears when i scroll down at certain point or when i refresh

Tags: css, html, scroll, fixed

I have a jquery plugin so i don´t know what is the problem, i tried to make it all again but whe i get to the fixed part it happens all again, i really don´t know what to do i must deliver this work by tomorrow

//This is my css

```
@media only screen and (max-width:360px) {
#menu a:link {
color : #FFF;
}
#menu a:visited {
color : #FFF;
}
#menu a:hover {
color : red;
}
#menu {
position : relative;
left : 0;
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
}
#logo {
width : 100%;
}
#menu ul {
position : relative;
left : 0;
height : auto;
top : 0;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
width : 100%;
margin : 0;
}
}

#menu{
font-family : 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
font-size : 15px;
position : relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
border: rgba(73, 73, 73, 0.3) solid 1px;
width: 100%;
background-image: url(grain.png);
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
text-align: center;
display: inline-block;

}
#menu ul {
list-style : none;
}
#menu li {
position : relative;
top : 69px;
line-height : 18px;
float : left;
}




@media only screen and (min-width:641px) {
#menu ul {
display : inline-block;
text-align : center;
height : 104px;
width: 980px;
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
#menu ul li a {
padding : 2px 0;
margin : 8px;
}
#menu ul li a:link {
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.2s;
transition-duration: 0.2s;
background : transparent;
width : 100%;
color : rgb(255, 255, 255);
text-decoration : none;
transition-duration : 0.2s;
}
#menu ul li a:visited {
width : 100%;
height : 104px;
color : rgb(255, 255, 255);
text-decoration : none;
background : transparent;
}
#menu ul li a:active {
width : 100%;
color : rgb(255, 255, 255);
text-decoration : none;
}
#menu ul li a:hover {
background : transparent;
border-bottom : 3px solid #fff;
color : #f4f4f4;
text-decoration : none;
}
}



@media only screen and (max-width:641px) {
#menu ul {
height : auto;
width : 100%;
}
#registro {
display : none;
}
}


#barra_arriba {
z-index : 30;
position : fixed;
left : 0;
top:0;
border : rgba(73, 73, 73, 0.3) solid 1px;
width : 100%;
background-image : url(grain.png);
background-color : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.53);
padding : 0;
margin : 0;
text-align : center;
display : inline-block;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s;
-moz-transition-duration: 0.4s;
transition-duration: 0.4s;
}

#barra_arriba img {
width: 238px;
float: left;
}

//AND THIS IS MY HTML

<div id="barra_arriba">
<div id="logo"></div>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li style="position:relative;top:0px;" ><img     src="http://www.imichproducciones.com/imagen/imich_producciones.png" alt="IMICH" class="logotipo"/>    </li>
<li id="tit"><a href="/" style="color:rgb(245, 0, 51);">IMICH</a></li>
<li><a href="/inscripciones/">INSCRIPCIONES</a></li>
<li><a href="/licenciatura/">LICENCIATURA</a></li>
<li><a href="/maestrias/">MAESTR&Iacute;AS</a></li>
<li><a href="/doctorado/">DOCTORADO</a></li>
<li><a href="/diplomados/">DIPLOMADOS</a></li>
<li><a href="/contacto/">CONTACTO</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DFyCh/

Comment: What EXACTLY is the problem?  What happens in the "fixed" part that is "broken"?

Comment: Please tell me that you indent your code and that the horror I see above is only due to however you got it into that window :)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with Chrome, it seems to be a bug that occurs when there is too much going on inside the page, I was able to fix it by adding the following transform code to the fixed position element, (`transform: translateZ(0);-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);`) that forces the browser to use hardware acceleration to access the device’s graphical processing unit (GPU) to make pixels fly. Web applications, on the other hand, run in the context of the browser, which lets the software do most (if not all) of the rendering, resulting in less horsepower for transitions. But the Web has been catching up, and most browser vendors now provide graphical hardware acceleration by means of particular CSS rules.

Using -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); will kick the GPU into action for the CSS transitions, making them smoother (higher FPS).

**Note:** translate3d(0,0,0) does nothing in terms of what you see. it moves the object by 0px in x,y and z axis. It's only a technique to force the hardware acceleration.

```
#barra_arriba {
    position: fixed;
    z-index...
    /* MAGIC HAPPENS HERE */
    transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```